# Regex replace for large number of search replace pairs

Tags: python, regex, nlp, text-processing

I want to be able to do large scale search and replace across documents for purposes of text normalisation.

For example:

1. Find all uses of **U.S.A**, **USA** and replace with **United States Of America**
2. Find all ampersands (&) and replace with the word **and**

I also want to be able to add new rules to the system without having to change any code. So the search replace pairs are stored in a data store that means anyone could add,update,remove the rules.

I've been working with the Python re module which is quite nice and ideally I would want to pass a list of tuples to the sub command for it to then go through each one and do the replacements. Is there a better way to do this other than iterating over a list of tuples and then creating a regular expression for each - it's very slow and inefficient especially with large documents:

```
replacements = [
  r('USA','United States Of America'),
  (r'U\.S\.A','United States Of America'),
  (r'US of A', 'United States of America')]

for replacement in replacements:
  document = re.sub(replacement[0],replacement[1],document
```

Comment: This question isn't really suited to SO's Q&A format. ([StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562))

Comment: @Mark, There is a Question in there somewhere, suggest rewriting it.

Comment: Ok, I've taken into account what you've said and tried to pose it as a question.

Comment: Nice, this is a much clearer question.

Comment: Blindly replacing & with and is a terrible idea. It may be part of formal names. Should "S&P 500" turn into "S and P 500"?

Answer (score 1):

None of your examples require regular expressions. Why not try good ol' string replacement?

```
replacements = [
    ('USA','United States Of America'),
    ('U\.S\.A','United States Of America'),
    ('US of A', 'United States of America')]

for replacement in replacements:
    document = document.replace(replacement[0], replacement[1])
```

That seems like it'd be slow, but you should benchmark it before ruling the approach out. Python is pretty good at stuff like this and the results might surprise you.

If you truly need regular expressions, you'll likely see a huge boost by compiling them:

```
replacements = [
    (re.compile('USA'),'United States Of America'),
    (re.compile('U\.S\.A'),'United States Of America'),
    (re.compile('US of A'), 'United States of America')]

for pattern, replacement in replacements:
    document = pattern.sub(replacement, document)
```

This saves Python the effort of having to re-compile those regexps every time you use them.

If you only need regexps some of the time, consider making two passes through the document: once with regexps, and once with string replacement. Or if you need some specific ordering of replacements, you could have something like:

```
replacements = [
    (re.compile('USA'),'United States Of America'),
    ('foo', 'bar'),
    (re.compile('U\.S\.A'),'United States Of America'),
    ('spam', 'eggs'),
    (re.compile('US of A'), 'United States of America')]

for pattern, replacement in replacements:
    try:
        document = pattern.sub(replacement, document)
    except AttributeError:
        document = document.replace(pattern, replacement)
```

Comment: The use of string.replace would be fine if you don't want to maintain the case of the original text as it doesn't allow you to ignore case as you can with a regex. So you would have to either lower or upper case the body of text and also the terms you are looking for, which affects the output.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Google Refine.

> Google Refine, a power tool for working with messy data

http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/

Answer (score 0):

I have a [Big Ass File](http://norvig.com/big.txt) with 6 MB of text. It is a compilation of several Project Gutenberg files.

Trying this:

```
reps = [
  (r'\bthousand\b','>>>>>1,000<<<<<'),
  (r'\bmillion\b',">>>>>1e6<<<<<"),
  (r'\b[Hh]undreds\b',">>>>>100's<<<<<"),
  (r'\bSherlock\b', ">>>> SHERLOCK <<<<")
  ]

t1=time.time()
out=[]  
rsMade=0
textLength=0
NewTextLen=0
with open('big.txt') as BigAssF:
    for line in BigAssF:
        textLength+=len(line)
        for pat, rep in reps:
            NewLine=re.subn(pat,rep,line)     

        out.append(NewLine[0])
        NewTextLen+=len(NewLine[0])
        rsMade+=NewLine[1]

print 'Text Length: {:,} characters'.format(textLength)
print 'New Text Length: {:,} characters'.format(NewTextLen)     
print 'Replacements Made: {}'.format(rsMade)     
print 'took {:.4} seconds'.format(time.time()-t1)
```

It prints:

```
Text Length: 6,488,666 characters
New Text Length: 6,489,626 characters
Replacements Made: 96
took 2.22 seconds
```

Which seems adequately fast to me.

You may have some issues with your code line:

`document = re.sub(replacement[0],replacement[1],document`

if that is not a typo.

How fast do you expect it to be?